# Makefile for C/C++ not working in V SCode

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code, makefile

I'm practicing my C in VS Code and I made a Makefile to get the object files, link them together and compile the program. I added the extension C/C++ Makefile Project and when I type 'make' in the terminal it says that make is not recognized as a cmdlet name... what can I do??

Error I get in terminal (is not recognized as a cmdlet name basically):

> make : The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:1

```
+ make
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[image: Folder with files and Makefile code]

Comment: Please read [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and update your question

Comment: One more thing. Would it be possible for you to translate that error to english? This site does have a focus on english only so it would be very useful if you could translate it.

Comment: sure, let me see if I can set the terminal's language to English, no prob

Comment: You don't need to do that. I'm assuming the error is in your language so you should be able to manually translate to english right? And then just edit the question

Comment: have you  installed make? Visual Studio Code is just an editor and doesn't come with any compilation tools

Comment: @SalvadorS Either the Make binaries for windows are not installed or the path variable to the binaries are missing.

Comment: `make` is not only searched as a cmdlet, but also as function, script file, or operable program, see the error message, read it all. So if you have `make` at all on your computer, the path to it is not set, or it is has another name. For example, MinGW used to name it "mingw32-make.exe", and you can copy it as "make.exe" or rename it.

Comment: Just checked that folder MinGW/bin/ and I don't have any make executable... I thought that it came with the VS Code extension. Where can I download and install those binaries?

Comment: help please, what can I do?